# Error while scheduling a batch script in windows xp?

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks, scheduling

I have a batch script snapshot.bat. I want to schedule that script on daily basis. But i am getting a following error :

`Task Scheduler Error 0x80070005: Access is denied.`

Please note that i do have admin rights on the system.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: run it as administrator.

Answer (score 2):

You need administrator rights to schedule tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the discovered potential for task run abuses by malware, Microsoft has deemed that all scheduled tasks must be run with password-protected administrative-level accounts only on Windows XP machines.

1. You MUST set up and use a password for the administrator account
   that you wish to run   the task from. When prompted during setting
   up the scheduling, enter the password that you have set up for your
   administrator account to complete the scheduling properly.This
   should resolve your problem.
2. If you face the problem even then, please confirm whether you can
   run the task manually (instead of running it by scheduling in task
   manager,) without a password-protected administrative account.

You can easily test this by setting up the password on the administrator account and scheduling the task .IF the task will not run manually, you should pursue additional issues 
which may be preventing the scheduling as well, though you will not likely encounter the same error code you posted, which is relative to the password-protected issue solely (as far as my informal research has indicated.)

Comment: i am adding the password, but still its not working. I can run the script manually from cmd promt